# Crystal App Initialized in $GOPATH Directory

Tags: go, crystal-lang

I have both Go and Crystal installed on macOS.

GOPATH Directory: **export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin**

Crystal Location: **/usr/local/bin/crystal**

When I initialize a crystal app with **crystal init app fizzbuzz**  (example) in the terminal, the fizzbuzz.cr is located in  **/usr/local/go/bin/fizzbuzz**.

How can I ensure it initializes in **/usr/local/bin/crystal** instead?

Comment: What is the directory where you're executing `crystal init app fizzbuzz` ? use `pwd` command in the terminal, please.

Comment: pwd --> /usr/local/bin

Comment: It's quite strange that it creates file not in the current directory, it should create project by default in the same directory where command is executed.  you can specify directory with a param `crystal init app fizzbuzz /usr/local/bin/crystal`

Comment: by the way `crystal init app fizzbuzz` will create project with the standard directory structure., not just one file.